# Create a game in matrix form - standalone

Tags: standalone

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{sgamevar}

\begin{document}

\begin{game}{3}{3}[P1][P2]
\> $\alt<6,7>{\textcolor{white}{L}}{L}$    \> $\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{C}}{C}$   \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{R}}{R}$\\
$\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{U}}{U}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{0,2}}{0,2}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,1}}{3,1}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{2,3}}{2,3}$\\
$\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{M}}{M}$ \> $\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{1,4}}{1,4}$ \> $\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,2}}{3,2}$ \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{4,1}}{4,1}$ \\
$\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{D}}{D}$ \> $\alt<6,7>{\textcolor{white}{2,1}}{2,1}$ \> $\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{4,4}}{4,4}$ \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,2}}{3,2}$
\end{game}

\end{document}
```

Basically, it works fine when I use it in a beamer presentation. Instead when I want to create it as a standalone document I got the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \alt 

l.9       \> $\alt
                  <6,7>{\textcolor{white}{L}}{L}$    \> $\alt<7>{\textcolor{...
```

Does anyone have an idea about why it happens? I used also

```
\usepackage{standalone}
```

but still does not work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\alt` is a macro defined by `beamer`, and really only makes sense in that class, I'm not sure what you expect the overlay specifications to do in `standalone`. Anyways, you can load the `beamerarticle` package, this defines `beamer` specific macros so that they can be used in other classes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\colorlet{unime}{blue}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{sgamevar}

\begin{document}

\begin{game}{3}{3}[P1][P2]
\> $\alt<6,7>{\textcolor{white}{L}}{L}$    \> $\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{C}}{C}$   \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{R}}{R}$\\
$\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{U}}{U}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{0,2}}{0,2}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,1}}{3,1}$ \> $\alt<3,4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{2,3}}{2,3}$\\
$\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{M}}{M}$ \> $\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{1,4}}{1,4}$ \> $\alt<5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,2}}{3,2}$ \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{4,1}}{4,1}$ \\
$\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{D}}{D}$ \> $\alt<6,7>{\textcolor{white}{2,1}}{2,1}$ \> $\alt<7>{\textcolor{unime}{4,4}}{4,4}$ \> $\alt<4,5,6,7>{\textcolor{white}{3,2}}{3,2}$
\end{game}

\end{document}
```